# Syntax for specifying spring xml files in ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-3

I am trying to find out the syntax for specifying the spring's XML file in the constructor of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. By syntax I don't mean the method signature but the actual string

For example the following three work.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/anshbansal/alarm/alarm.xml");
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:alarm.xml");
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("alarm.xml");
```

I have googled and tried to go through the `Spring 3.1.0` source code also. But I got stuck after `doResolvePlaceholders` method in `org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver` class of  Spring. Specificaly I was not able to understand how placeholders are resolving to the path.

Can anyone share what is the syntax for the string to specify the xml file?

**EDIT**

I mean the syntax to specify path to spring xml file like in the constructor. I do not mean the syntax of the xml file itself.

Comment: I am afraid that people did not answer your problem, because the problem is not clear. What is it that you actually need - syntax to specify path to spring xml file or you are looking for syntax of the spring xml config file (its contents), i.e. this http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html?

Comment: @MichalWilkowski Forgot to @ you after updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand the question now :-). PropertyResolver is used only to put environment values (or property file values) into spring XML file, i.e.:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///some/path/file.properties"/>
```

and then resolving them inside this spring xml, i.e.:

```
<bean id="mailInviteMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="${mail.from}"/>
    <property name="subject" value="${mail.subject}"/>
</bean>
```

Putting spring XML in the classpath and naming in standard convention (i.e. beans.xml) is preferable. However, you may configure it putting a parameter to java invocation, i.e.

```
java -Dmy.parameter=/path/to/beans.xml ...
```

and then loading it manually:

```
Context context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(System.getProperty("my.parameter"));
```

Comment: I think there is still some misunderstanding. Would you look at the three examples that I have given? The only difference is the String passed as the argument to the constructor. I want to find out what are the different allowed ways to write this String. Maybe it's not specific to spring and thus causing the confusion.